# Finding "Type of Service" code(s) for specific procedures/CPT codes

Tags: health-informatics

How do healthcare providers find the right "Type of Service" code(s) for Coverage inquiries/Claims?

From what I gather, in order to get an accurate answer for Coverage inquiries and Claim submission one needs to come up with the right Type of Service code(s).

I am interested in this in the context of EDI/X12.

Comment: can you specify more about the context.

Comment: CPT codes are copyrighted by AMA and it can be hard to get details about each code. CMS is using them and includes them in HCPCS code set. CPT codes are part of UMLS and can be retrieved from there.

Comment: How can I reverse conversion of my answer to comment?

Comment: please post one CPT code (as a use case and example) for which you want to find type of service.